# Copy SVG from inside a hidden div to create a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a page where i am rendering some charts. These are fusion charts. I have a grid layout where each grid box is clickable and on click the divs in which the charts are rendered are shown. By default these divs are hidden and once the respective anchor tag is clicked the corresponding chart is shown. Now what i want is that the grid boxes should have a resized thumbnail image of the chart that is being rendered. i am trying to copy the svg but i cant since it seems i cannot copy content from a hidden div. Below is the piece of code i am mainly interested in.

```
 $("#testButton").on('click',function (){
    var testDiv = $("#chart-container").clone();
    console.log($(testDiv.html()))
    var testSvg = $(testDiv.html()).find('svg').clone();

testSvg.appendTo($("#testDiv"))
})
```

If you notice in the above code only when the div `$("#chart-container")` is shown it works. Otherwise i am not able to copy the svg element. What i would want is that when the charts are loaded in the hidden divs the corresponding grid boxes should have a thumbnail of their resized svgs.

**In the i have provided only the first grid box contains a chart rest contain some text** https://jsfiddle.net/nyb4v4og/.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should use `find` on the div, not the html contents of the div.
Try `var testSvg = $(testDiv).find('svg').clone();`
You shouldn't need to clone the chart contents if you're going to clone the svg anyway.

```js
$("#testButton").on('click',function (){
    var testSvg = $("#contents").find('svg').clone();
    testSvg.appendTo($("#target"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hidden-source" style="display:none;">
 <div id="contents">
  <svg width="100" height="40"><text x="10" y="25">Test</text></svg>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="target"></div>
<div id="testButton">Test button</div>
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier but it was not working .... i have updated the fiddle with your suggestion but still it does not copy until the div containing the svg is shown .... you can check out the latest fiddle ... below is the code change ... 

$("#testButton").on('click',function (){      
        var testSvg = $("#chart-container").find('svg').clone();
        
    testSvg.appendTo($("#testDiv"))
     }) 

https://jsfiddle.net/nyb4v4og/3/

Comment: I don't really understand how you're generating the charts, but the svg doesn't exist until you click the link (i.e. it's not that it's hidden it's that it doesn't exist in the DOM). Jquery can't find it until it's there. As far as I can tell the Fusion chart is not created until it is shown.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the response .... and yes you are correct ... and they dont have a functionality to render charts in hidden divs.... i came up with a workaround for my initial problem that i am rendering the charts in a div of 2 px and on click of the grid i am cloning the desired charts .... now all i have to do is to resize the svg rendered in the divs of 2 px to fit the size of the grid i have in place .... any help with that ???

Comment: Is that included in your fiddle? SVG should just rescale by itself to fill the space. If you are setting the height and width of the SVG, then you could change them with JQuery.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle .... now you can see the chart on clicking the first block of the grid ... i want to now copy the svg of the chart so i can use it as a thumbnail image of the grid ..... fushioncharts has a function getSVGString() which copies the string but i am unable to manipulate it to fit my grid box properly